No bootable image after installation Xubuntu
Let me preface that this is an old computer with a main board from 2009 (Intel DP35DP). As far as I know this predates UEFI, Secure Boot, etc.
I used Rufus to flash a USB drive and then proceeded to install the latest Xubuntu release (24.04). I used the default installer for the installation process and chose to use the whole disc as I plan for Xubuntu to be the only OS on the computer.
After installation when it comes time to boot from the SSD the computer states 'no bootable device'. Grub doesn't even show up.
This is totally baffling to me as I've installed Linux on this computer in the past without issues and on plenty of other machines too. In the past as in many times since I first built it from 2009 onwards. I have installed dozens of Linux distributions onto it over the years without any sort of issue like this.
I checked the BIOS and the drive is detected. When I boot back into the live environment to try installing again, it too recognizes the drive as having Xubuntu installed onto it.
I have redownloaded the image and reflashed several USB sticks with the same result. I am reasonably sure the many images I have downloaded and are valid.
Has something changed recently with the installation process or is my computer too old?
(conclusion)
I tried several different distributions and they managed to install. So I'll stick to them. I'm unsure why Xubuntu didn't but I guess something just wasn't playing nice with it and my hardware.
That was somewhat of a let down as I preferred Xubuntu but I'll just have to make do with what I can get to work on my computer.
Thank you for all suggestions and time making them

You've provided no actual Xubuntu release details; nor what installer you're using (installers vary on release & you've not yet said).  The oldest system I use in QA of Xubuntu is a 2005 HP Compaq, and it installs all release of Xubuntu up to Xubuntu 24.04 LTS.   Common problems are avoided if you validate ISO after download & write using an approved method (and/or diff the written image to ensure it was correctly written).   Failure to boot can be the result of a reformatted ISO write that confused the installer; write the ISO as per documentation for your release

The oldest device I used in QA of Xubuntu 24.04 LTS was a 2005 HP Compaq, and I had no issues with it.  Yes things have changed; as occurs with releases every six months, you mention "in the past" without any context of when so how can we have a clue as to how long ago you're wondering about...  Xubuntu 24.04 LTS uses the ubuntu-desktop-installer, where a few issues appear in QA that caused an option I loved with 23.10 & earlier being disabled for now on 24.04, but hopes is to get that feature fixed in time. Your details imply I'd be checking user procedural tasks first

Did you validate ISO after download??  Did you write ISO as is documented correctly?  (don't forget releases after 20.04 can differ to 20.04 & earlier; thus some software needs to be updated to write the ISO correctly if the ISO is reformatted - what options did you use; as only simple clones of ISO will work for all releases which is why that option is recommended in doco & used in QA) Did you verify ISO was written correctly via diff etc.. ie. check what you did as you haven't specified what checks you did, how written, what sofware etc...

Have you explored your rufus writing of ISOs?  as releases newer than 20.04 require an updated rufus app for releases where reformat of ISO is used (rather than simple clone; and rufus options allow you to reformat so ISO will boot in some hardware (eg. uEFI) but not legacy).  Your re-writes of ISOs if using the same method each time could be the issue, as you don't specify how you wrote using rufus except that's an app that has reformat options which need to match release to work and can cause bootloader to write incorrectly! if wrong options are used for your hardware
